# How do I remove the deprecated UIAlertView from my code without significant refactoring?

Tags: ios, uialertview, deprecated

I have an objective-C app running on iOS.  When I wrote it originally I used numerous `UIAlert`s to communicate with the user, but these are now deprecated, so I need to change to `UIAlertController` with a `preferredStyle` of `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` instead.

This seems relatively simple, except that I now need to present the `UIAlertController` to the current `UIViewController`.  To do that, I need to know what the current `UIViewController` is.

This is a problem for an alert that is displayed by a separate class that is not itself part of the display stack.  I can’t just say:

```
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

because `self` here doesn’t have a `presentViewController` method.

I see two possible solutions, but I don’t like either of them, for the reasons given:

1. Find the current `UIRootViewController` by using the code suggested (thank you!) by  https://stackoverflow.com/users/4720315/mannam-brahmam, i.e.

   ```
    UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [vc presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

   This works okay, but seems unnecessarily complicated, given that before `UIAlert` was deprecated, it was completely unnecessary (I just declared the alert and then did `[alert show];` without regard to what the current `viewController` was).
2. Stop issuing alerts from a subsidiary class altogether - return a status code and have the invoking `viewController` issue the alert instead.

   This may actually be a better design, so maybe I should have started out like this, but at this point it would involve a lot of refactoring.

Is there a third option that I’m not seeing?

Why would Apple deprecate `UIAlertView` if it causes this amount of refactoring?

Comment: I would not suggest any code gimick. I guess you should do it the hard way. And for future don't use it directly. Use it through your class.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @amar.  The code is not a gimmick, it simply finds the current RootViewController.  My issue is just that it's more complicated than before the deprecation.

Comment: The recommended way to present `UIAlertController` – even in Objective-C – is a category (in Swift extension) of `UIViewController`.

Comment: That's useful information, @vadian.  However at the point where I need to present the alert, I don't have access to the current `UIViewController`, hence the need to retrieve it via `UIApplication`.